# How do you decide when to create a collection versus a embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm currently in the process of learning noSQL via MongoDB but my schooling and work experience is with relational databases.

I currently have a Users collection and I need to implement functionality that stores the amount of webpage hits for the user profile page, and around 5 more stats.

Should I create a new collection to store this information or should I create an embedded document to store these 6 pieces of information in the Users collection?

Thanks!

Comment: I would add a bit of thought into how the application is going to consume it as well. There could be benefits in producing documents that are more "scenario/view" specific in context, and it might not make sense to pull up a huge document everytime, just to leverage a subset of data, each time looking the same for that view. But again, don't know how your application looks. If I used event sourcing I would create more view specific read models, and then probably split your case up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create embedded documents until they just don't make sense anymore to include under one collection. A stats related to a User document makes 100% sense to store embedded. Simply put...a User profile has stats. The stats don't make any sense for any other collection.

If you end up having a collection that really needs references because many different collections might reference a single document, then it makes sense to split that into a collection and use id references. When you start thinking about having to update many other documents when you change something in one embedded document, then it might be good to move to a unique collection. That way each document only refers to an id, which can change its document data at any time.

Comment: To add to this, I feel that the concept of an 'Aggregate Root' from DDD ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design ) fits really well in this discussion. If something makes sense on it's own is certainly one of the most important things to think about in that discussion. Access-patterns, lifecycle of the embedded doc (i.e: Uml  composite vs aggregate discussion) are a couple of others.